wp redirect users only when logging in (1 time) if on homepage
I have the following code to redirect users which are logged in and on the homepage:
function add_login_check()
{
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(7) ) {
    ?>
    <script>window.location='/user-area/'</script>

    <?php
    exit();
  }
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');

But I am trying to modify it to only redirect users as they actually login (only to redirect once (as they login)), rather than every time they visit the homepage whilst they are logged in.
I have tried using session as follows:
function add_login_check()
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['didit'])) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page(7) ) {
    ?>
    <script>window.location='/user-area/'</script>

    <?php
    exit();
  }
    $_SESSION['didit'] = true; 
}
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');

Also adding session_start(); to the beginning of my theme, but I can't get it to work :( I'd really appreciate any help, thanks so much!!!

Is this a JS problem or a PHP problem? Keep in mind that "only to redirect once" can only achieved if you store whether the user was already redirected or not, and neither the session nor the cookies are the proper place for this, as they might get removed by either the server or the browser. Store such a flag in the database instead

sorry yes its a php problem.

I think that you can achieve this by altering your code a little bit.
function add_login_check()
{
if(!isset($_SESSION['didit'])) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_page() ) {
    ?>

    <script>window.location='/user-area/'</script>

    <?php
    exit();
    $_SESSION['didit'] = true; //Esssentially your session declaration here is unreachable , because there is a redirection and a `exit()` before it.
  }

}
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');

Please try the code like this .
function add_login_check()
{
if(!isset($_COOKIE['didit'])) {
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_home() ) {

setcookie("didit", true, 0, "/"); // Setted a cookie with the name of "didit" and the value of "true" , with lifetime of 0 ( meaning that when the browser closes the cookie will be expired

    ?>

    <script>window.location='/user-area/'</script>

    <?php
    exit();
  }

}
}
add_action('wp', 'add_login_check');

You can also use is_home() or is_front_page() instead of is_page(page_id) that you are currently using as far as you intent to use this code
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_home/
https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_front_page/
I also believe that cookie is a better practice than session variable , because you can alter the cookie life span , from 0 ( browser closes means that cookie is expires from x amount of time).
https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.cookies.php
The current code and changes are untested , so please if you test them you can give feedback and i can assist you further. Cheers!

thanks so much for this! really appreciate it! yes that works great! legend! thanks again!!!!!!!!!!!!!!1
